# mysql function for counting on/off time

Tags: mysql

I have the fields to mySQL database

id - date - time - status

status has value 0 for OFF and 1 for ON

example

```
22145 - 2016-06-10 - 06:10:45 - 0
22145 - 2016-06-10 - 06:13:45 - 1
22145 - 2016-06-10 - 06:17:45 - 1
22145 - 2016-06-10 - 06:20:45 - 1
22145 - 2016-06-10 - 06:25:45 - 0
22145 - 2016-06-10 - 23:30:00 - 1
22145 - 2016-06-11 - 00:13:45 - 1
22145 - 2016-06-11 - 00:15:45 - 0
```

Is there a way for mySQL to return

1. Count on/off times for selected 'id' and for selected date/dates

example return for above data

```
id=22145  startdate=2016-06-10  enddate=2016-06-11

22145 - 2016-06-10 - 06:13:45 - 12
22145 - 2016-06-10 - 23:30:45 - 30
22145 - 2016-06-11 - 00:00:01 - 15
```

2. Count on/off time (sum) for selected 'id' and for selected date/dates

example return for above data

```
22145 - 2016-06-10 - N/A - 42
22145 - 2016-06-11 - N/A - 15
```

i tryied something like this but does not work

```
BEGIN

DECLARE test INT;
DECLARE _prev INT;
DECLARE i INT;
DECLARE starting_time TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE stoping_Time TIMESTAMP;
DECLARE total_time INT;
DECLARE c1 date;
DECLARE c2 time;

SET c1 = '0000-01-01';
SET c2 = '00:00:00';
SET total_time = 0;   
SET i=0;
SET test = 0;
SET _prev = 0;
SET starting_time = '00-00-00 00:00:00';
SET stoping_time = '00-00-00 00:00:00';
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE time_table(t time,d date,c int);

INSERT INTO time_table(
SELECT time, date,c 
FROM `tank_data` 
WHERE id = "22145"
LIMIT 10);



   label1: LOOP
     /* test=   (
         SELECT * FROM time_table
         LIMIT 1
         OFFSET i
         );

     SET i = i + 1;
    */
     IF _prev = 0  THEN

         SET _prev = 1;
         SELECT date FROM time_table LIMIT 1 OFFSET i into c1;
         SELECT time FROM time_table LIMIT 1 OFFSET i into c2;
         SELECT concat((c1),' ',(c2)) INTO starting_time;

     ELSEIF _prev =1  THEN

         SET _prev = 0;
         SELECT date FROM time_table LIMIT 1 OFFSET i into c1;
         SELECT time FROM time_table LIMIT 1 OFFSET i into c2;
         SELECT concat((c1),' ',(c2)) INTO stoping_time;       

         SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(stoping_time,starting_time)) INTO total_time; 

     END IF;  

     SET i = i + 1;

     IF i=5 THEN
            LEAVE label1;
     END IF;


     ITERATE label1;

     LEAVE label1;
   END LOOP label1;

   RETURN total_time;

END
```

I have **done it in jquery** but it is too slow

thank you

Comment: "I need ... requirement 1, requirement 2..." - please do not confuse SO with a free coding service. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask What have you tried yet? What is your concrete question?

Comment: Sorry my first time... Rephrased it

Comment: No worries, welcome to SO and thanks for the edit!

Comment: I can't understand your first example: `22145 - 2016-06-10 - 06:13:45 - 12` why are there 3 rows for id 22145? If you want count for 'on' and 'off' there must be two result rows. And why last column (count?) has values 12, 30 and 15 if there are only 8 rows in example?

Comment: In mySQL table we hold multiple readings during time for multiple id's

Comment: Example:  22145 started at  2016-06-10 - 06:13:45 , still running at 06:13:45  .... and stoped at 06:25:45...  so it was running for 12 mins starting 06:16:45..... Second result is untill 23:59:59 (same day) third result is from 00:00:01 next day ..Function  1 counts o/off times during same day  and function 2 counts running time as sum for whole day

Comment: First, store date and time as a single entity.

Comment: How do you know from this data that the status was OFF at 2016-06-10 00:00:00 but ON at 2016-06-11 00:00:00? Does the status remain ON until the next OFF row, even if this spans multiple days?

Comment: It records start stop times . Since no stop recorded it is still running. If a start recorded at 23:00:00 and a stop at 01:00:00 Then it was running at 00:00:00 (change of day)